# execute a method from protractor and get the return value

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Can I execute a method from protractor and get the return value of the method?

For example: I use `jqxGrid` widget, and the widget have a method that return the table details in json, how can I import the variable to the protractor project.

The method I want to call in the project:

```
var table = $("#Grid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'json');
```

The test in the protractor:

```
it("Get table", function(){

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Locate the grid and call `jqxGrid()` method on it's [`WebElement`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement) through [`executeScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

```
var elm = element(by.id("Grid"));
var data = browser.executeScript("return arguments[0].jqxGrid('exportdata', 'json');", elm.getWebElement());
```